# Stripe metered billing approach

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm about to integrate stripe as payment gateway for my client's website. My client's plan is to bill the organization based on the number of users active for that organization every month. For example, if the organization has 10 users and only 8 were active, then at the end of the month the organization will be charged 8 x $20 per user per month = $160. The number of active users may vary every month.

So, considering the above scenario, can you please clarify me on the following questions on how this could be setup under stripe?

1. The organization must be charged at the end of the month
2. If the organization has subscribed in the middle of the month, then they should be charged on pro rate basis. (example: subscription date is 10th Mar, and assume we are in last day 31st Mar, and the organization had 6 active users as on 31st Mar, then $20/31 days * 20 * 6 = $77.42 is what the organization must be charged)

Can you please help me with the steps and suggestions if any?

Thanks,
Hemant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually quite straightforward.

You need to combine Stripe's [metered billing](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing#reporting-usage) with a [billing cycle anchor](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#new-subscriptions).

Firstly, you need to create a "price" for the billing. This can be done via the API. Notice the `interval`, the `usage_type`, `currency` and `unit_amount`:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

const price = await stripe.prices.create({
  currency: 'usd',
  recurring: {
    interval: 'month',
    usage_type: 'metered'
  },
  product_data: {
    name: 'Gold special',
  },
  nickname: 'Gold special price',
  unit_amount: 3000,
});
```

You then need to create a subscription, making sure **not to pass in the `quantity`** param. Make sure to record the output `subscription item ID` - this is used to report on the usage.

Once you have the payment created, you need to set up a subscription using a the `billing cycle anchor`. The anchor is a UNIX timestamp in seconds from the current UNIX timestamp.

To achieve your desired effect, you need to create an anchor that triggers on the 31st of the month. When a given month does not have a 31st, it will trigger the invoice on the last day of the month:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: 'cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a',
  items: [
    {
      price: 'price_CBb6IXqvTLXp3f',
    },
  ],
  billing_cycle_anchor: 1611008505, // Calculate current time in seconds until anchor date
});
```

This will automatically be prorated as explained in the documentation.

The two examples I've given are very simple and there's a lot more configuration you can do but I hope they help as a starting point. Please read the two documentation links at the top of the answer to see how to configure everything else you might need.

Comment: Thanks Jordan for the heads-up. So 2 quick questions in the above setup:

Comment: 1. When creating price object, I can pass in my custom product name, nickname and price as $20. Correct?
2. When creating subscription object, I pass the customer obj, price obj and billing cycle anchor to current month end date time in milliseconds. Correct?
3. The above subscription object is created using last day of a month. Is this one subscription is enough and will bill the customers every month end automatically based on prorate?
4. I'm thinking about making use of the billing portal page provided by Stripe allowing the customers to manage cards and payments. Is that a good idea?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes, I think. 3) Yes, but I'm not entirely sure how to handle it if you're starting on a month that has less days. For example if you start on 28th Feb, I'm not sure if it will continue on the 28th of March or the end of March. You may have to stop/start the subscription between months until one has 31 days (or perhaps stripe has an inbuilt way to handle this. Their support is excellent so I suggest you ask). 4) This would be good for an MVP but unfortunately right now it doesn't support updating subscriptions with metered billing

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/customer-portal#roadmap @Hemant regarding the metered billing